# What if we open a file in write mode in two different terminals and try to write them at the same time?

Tags: python, file

```
f=open("text.txt","w")
f.write("What is this?")
```

And in the new terminal:

```
x=open("text.txt","w")
x.write("I am going to do the same.")
x.close()
```

then I tried to read and print the contents of the file :

```
x=open("text.txt","r")
print(x.read())
What is this? do the same. #this is the output. I want to understand how this happened.
```

Comment: try closing the file after writing, and also use append mode

Comment: The actual behavior in a race condition is system-dependent, and not always predictable. Please [edit] to specify your platform, or be satisfied with "it depends". (Calling your local command prompt a "terminal" suggests a Unix-like system, but this could differ between U*xes, too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has happened here is that in your first session, the output is still buffered after you have done the `f.write(...)`.  (Note that you have not closed the file.)  In your new terminal, you write to the file using a starting file pointer of 0, and then the output buffers are fully flushed to the file because you close the file.

If you were to inspect the output file immediately after you have done this, then you would find that the contents were simply `I am going to do the same.`.  However, it must be that by the time that you inspected the file you had flushed the contents of the buffer from the first session -- this might be for example because you had exited from the python session, or because you had done an explicit `f.close()` or `f.flush()`.  This would then cause the buffered `What is this?` to be written to the file.  But the starting file pointer is also 0, because the original `open` in the first session would have positioned it at the start (also truncating any existing contents).  So it will overwrite part of the previous `I am going to do the same.`, leading to the observed behaviour.

If you have two processes both appending to the same file and you want to be sure to avoid conflicting writes, then you would need to do the following:

- open files in `a` or `r+` mode
- when one process wants to write, it must:

  - wait for an exclusive lock on the file
  - seek to the end of the file
  - write the output
  - flush the output
  - release the lock

But the details of file locking are out of scope for this question.